# What's a good way to prototype a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testing, uikit

Right now I just edit my `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate`, and make it the first thing I see (which is pretty annoying). One option I've heard is a UI test with a very long sleep statement. Is there a better option?

To be clear, I’m not trying to create an automated, UI test suite. I just want an easier way to manually test a graphical part of my code that doesn't involve temporarily changing the code path for my project.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe you could add a playground to your project to play around with UI stuff manually.

Comment: You were right. I went the playground route and I think it's going to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an adequate solution. As was suggested, I decided to use playgrounds. I created a framework target for my main project. I added my project and my playground to the same workspace. Then I imported the framework into my playground. I used [this blog](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/adding-playgrounds-to-xcode-projects/) as a guide.

I also found that using `@testable` when you import your framework makes it so that you don't need to mark everything in your project as public just so you can use it in your playground.

Example: `@testable import FrameworkName`